# Android Raw Folder Path

Tags: android

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("//raw//mydb.db",
                null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

        if(db.isOpen())
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DB opened", 2).show();
    }
}
```

İn my raw folder have mydb.db, when i want to connect mydb, im write to path for "//raw//mydb.db"  but not working..

How i can solve this problem?

Comment: this "//raw//mydb.db" will not work because it would not exists. also what do you mean by "but not working". which line is not working, first, second, last??? please post enough details along with stacktrace for us to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. `//raw//mydb.db` is not a valid path
2. Resources are read-only, and so you cannot open a `SQLiteDatabase` on a raw resource

If your objective is to package a database with your app, that your app uses as a starting point at runtime, [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

Comment: @user1429570: I am going to assume that your answer is supposed to be a comment on my answer. You are welcome to copy the raw resource to a file if you want. That is what `SQLiteAssetHelper` does. However, regardless of how it gets there, **you need a local file**, as SQLite cannot use a raw resource.

Comment: or how i can use local db file? ( not recommend raw folder )